# How do I block TinEye spider?

Tags: block, robots.txt, privacy, google-image-search

I know how to block Google image search through robots.txt, is there something similar for TinEye? I do not want my sites being indexed by them.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
Please see: [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273) (don't just change your question to "How").

Comment: You might want to check https://gist.github.com/ai2ik/29863837a888800f2f242326985d245c#file-bad-bots-L47

Answer (score 0):

Put this into robots.txt:

```
User-agent: Tineye
Disallow:/
```